# RSSL_PAD_ISO10126 Padding method in php

Tags: php, oracle, encryption, aes

I have a client using oracle pass through authentication, and I'm having trouble getting the encryption right.

This is all of the information I have from the client:

1. secretKey = 32 character string given to me
2. a list of parameters to be encrypted.
3. Encoding method is Base 64 encoding.
4. Encryption method is aes256.
5. KegGen method is PKCS5-V20.
6. Padding method is RSSL_PAD_ISO10126.
7. To make sure the URL is safe, certain characters must be replaced. (+ becomes _ ; / becomes ~ ; and = becomes *).

So far I have the following code, but I'm not 100% I am doing the encryption right, and also do not know how to implement the RSSL_PAD_ISO10126 padding, or what to do with the PKCS5-V20 keygen. I found another post on here that explained that aes256 encryption was MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128. Any information on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static function ptaLink($pid, $params = [])
{
    $url = \Config::get('chat.ptaBaseUrl');

    $params['p_userid'] = $pid;
    $params['p_ccf_1'] = $pid;

    $ptaDataString = self::buildParams($params);

    return $url.$ptaDataString;
}

public static function buildParams($params) {

    $defaultParams = [
        'p_userid' => '', // PID
        'p_passwd' => '',
        'p_ccf_1' => '', // PID
        'p_li_expiry' => time(),
    ];

    $params = array_merge($defaultParams, $params);

    //Convert PTA data array to string
    $ptaDataString = "";
    foreach($params as $key=>$value)
    {
        $ptaDataString .= ($ptaDataString === "") ? '' : '&';
        $ptaDataString .= "$key=$value";
    }

    $ptaDataString = self::encryptData($ptaDataString);

    return $ptaDataString;
}

public static function encryptData($text) {

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $key = \Config::get('chat.secretKey');

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    //Base64 encode the data
    $ptaDataString = base64_encode($crypttext);

    //Make sure the data is URL safe
    $ptaDataString = strtr($ptaDataString, array('+' => '_', '/' => '~', '=' => '*'));

    return $ptaDataString;

}
```

Comment: Eh, so basically you have just the `mcrypt_encrypt` call and we have to program the rest?

Comment: No, i believe everything is correct except for the padding implementation in RSSL_PAD_ISO10126. I was able to infer from the spec (and this post http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/why-was-iso10126-padding-withdrawn), exactly what that padding method is, but am not sure exactly how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Implemention here for anyone that ever needs this, https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/lib/CryptLib/Encryption/PackingMode/ISO10126.php